# colour cell based on value (date) on another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, colors, iteration, range

I have several dates on the Column D of sheet 2. I want to search the first row of sheet 1 and if the same date is found colour the cells but can't seem to make it work.
I believe the issue is on the ranges, but tried several ways and nothing works.

Please see my code below:

```
Sub test2()

Dim xcel As Range
Dim ycel As Range
Dim WS1 As Worksheet
Dim WS2 As Worksheet
Dim lc As Long
Dim lr As Long

Set WS1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
Set WS2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2")


lc = WS1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lr = WS2.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With WS1
    For Each xcel In .Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, lc))
        For Each ycel In WS2.Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(lr, 4))
            If xcel.Value = ycel.Value Then
                xcel.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                xcel.Font.ColorIndex = 1
            End If
        Next ycel
    Next xcel
End With
End Sub
```

thank you in advance

Comment: One thing that jumps out is you are using `Cells` that is unqualified -- that is, `Cells` is referring to the currently active sheet, and not necessarily the sheet you want to refer to. So you might use `.Cells` or `WS2.Cells` and see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, test the next way. It uses two arrays, for faster iteration against iteration between each cells and create a `Union` range for the matching cells, which to be colored at the end, at once:

```
Sub test2ColorCellInt()
 Dim WS1 As Worksheet, arr1, WS2 As Worksheet, arr2
 Dim lc As Long, lr As Long, i As Long, j As Long, rngCol As Range

 Set WS1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
 Set WS2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2")


 lc = WS1.cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
 lr = WS2.Range("D" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 arr1 = WS1.Range(WS1.cells(1, 1), WS1.cells(1, lc)).value 'place the range in an array for faster iteration
 arr2 = WS2.Range(WS2.cells(2, 4), WS2.cells(lr, 4)).value 'place the range in an array for faster iteration

 For i = 1 To UBound(arr1, 2) 'iterate on columns of arr1:
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr2) 'iterate between rows of arr2:
        If arr1(1, i) = arr2(j, 1) Then 'in case of a match:
            If rngCol Is Nothing Then   'if the range to keep the matching cells is nothing
                Set rngCol = WS1.cells(1, i) 'create the range
            Else
                Set rngCol = Union(rngCol, WS1.cells(1, i)) 'make a Union between existing and the matching cell
            End If
        End If
    Next j
 Next i
 If Not rngCol Is Nothing Then 'if the range exists, do the job:
    rngCol.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    rngCol.Font.ColorIndex = 1
 End If
End Sub
```

It, probably, will be good to preliminarily clear the format of the first row existing cells, to see the differences when running the code next time, but if not requested, I did not include such an approach...

Your existing code wrongly qualified the used ranges, using the same `cells` of the active sheet for building both of them. But I tried to supply a faster way of dealing with the issue.

Comment: thank you again for your precious help @Faneduru